Retrieve the next working day of date in SQL Developer (db Oracle)
I need to retrieve the next working day of date in SQL Developer (db Oracle)
I need to use a case and a function to calculate the next working day
CASE WHEN ( (**Next working day** (start_date) ) = end_date ) THEN 0 ELSE 1

I expect to use a function.

How do you define a working day?

Working days depend on countries. So, there is no function to get this information. Best practice of this you need to create a date table and insert dates, working days, holidays etc. into it for your location. And then use this table (join etc.) in your select statement.
